# Download file on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are working on a web application in which you have to enter some personal details in a form. Once you submit the form, the server creates a PDF-file containing these details. Rather than redirecting to another page, we would like to have an automatic download like in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D572L/).

```
var url = 'data:application/octet-stream,Testing%20one%20two%20three';
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.setAttribute('href', url);
anchor.setAttribute('download', 'myNote.txt');
```

The main difficulty here (as in the example) is that the server does not store the PDF. It generates it and then throws it away. Hence there is no url. Is it still somehow possible to get the "automatic download"-effect?

Comment: You may want to check out this article on saving files on the client side. 

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Comment: You are saying *...the server creates a PDF-file* , can't you just force the browser to download the file by sending the appropriated header back to the client?